# How to get variable from input NodeJs

Tags: node.js, readline

I want to get a value from input

```
const readline = require('node:readline/promises').createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
})

const value = await readline.question('enter :');
console.log(value)
readline.close()
```

And then I get an Error "SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules"
On the other hand in the docs example:

```
import * as readline from 'node:readline/promises';
import { stdin as input, stdout as output } from 'process';

const rl = readline.createInterface({ input, output });

const answer = await rl.question(
  'What do you think of Node.js? '
);

console.log(
  `Thank you for your valuable feedback: ${answer}`
);

rl.close();
```

I copy this example and get the same error. I cant use readline synchronously. I want input a value, some variable will equals this value, and THEN it will console.log(). I dont want to use "Prompt" module. TY

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is because you are trying to use `top-level-await`.

Now this is possible in modern nodejs (16+ I think), but you need to tell explicitly node to use modules, like your in your second code.

Try to upgrade nodeJS to the latest version 18, it should run fine.

(Also you may need to hint node on using modules explicitly, for that either name your file using the extension `.mjs` or specify `"type": "module"` in your `package.json`

> Working example using `.mjs` and current node `v18.6` the code is copy pasted from your question, no changes made.
> [image: working example]